# AWS Elastic Container Registry login blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

We are trying to log in to AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) to pull down docker containers from our private registry.  The login is failing with this error:

Error response from Daemon: Get https://... EOF

We believe that the AWS CLI is making a call to some AWS service that is being blocked by our security software, but we cannot find documentation on what endpoints and ports we need to whitelist besides the docker registry URL itself.

Does anyone know what AWS endpoints need to be whitelisted in a secure environment for AWS ECR to authenticate correctly?

Any help here is greatly appreciated